# Subtract values in dataframe based on condition from another dataframe

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame containing AHD values at different years and months for a bunch of sites. I have another data frame with elevation data for up to 4 plots at each site. I need to subtract the measured AHD from the elevation for each plot in each wetland. This is a large data set, so I have been trying to use loops to minimise the amount of code needed.

I have been trying to use nested loops to pull vales from one data frame to subtract from another data.frame. I can't seem to get it to work.

```
# Example data
Dates <- rep(seq(as.Date("1/1/2010"), by = "month", length.out = 24),5)
Site <- rep(letters[1:5], each=24)
AHD <- runif(120, min = 12, max = 50)
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(as.Date(Dates), Site, AHD))
df1$AHD <- as.numeric(df1$AHD)

Site <- rep(letters[1:5], each=4)
Plot <- rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 4 )],5)
elv <- runif(20, min = 12, max = 50)
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(Site, Plot, elv))
df2$elv <- as.numeric(df2$elv)
```

What I am after is a data.frame containing adjusted AHD values for each plot  at each site. The resulting data.frame will have the columns 'data', 'site', 'plot' and 'adjAHD' where 'adjAHD' = df1$AHD - df2$elv. This dataframe will have 600 (120 x 5) rows as each date at each site will be replicated for the four plots.

Comment: Your example have duplicate entries for the common column 'Site', otherwise, a `merge` or join would do it

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps I didn't ask the question clearly. I need to create a totally new data frame that will use the elv values from df2 to calculate new adjAHD values for each plot at each timepoint at each site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method akrun explained:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "Site")
df3$adjAHD <- df3$AHD - df3$elv

head(df3)
# Site      V1 AHD Plot elv adjAHD
# 1    a -719143  86    A   4     82
# 2    a -719143  86    B  15     71
# 3    a -719143  86    C  17     69
# 4    a -719143  86    D   9     77
# 5    a -719112  45    A   4     41
# 6    a -719112  45    B  15     30

dim(df3)
# [1] 480   6
```

Comment: side note (120 x "four plots") = 480

Comment: Great thanks! One question. why do the elv values change after being merged?

Comment: They don't, the data is just ordered differently than you are expecting.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much

Comment: `df3 <- df3[order(df3$V1),]`